# multipeer connectivity for video streaming between iphones

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, video-streaming, multipeer-connectivity

i've been searching on this for some days now. I've found how to connect devices with the multipeer connectivity protocol (http://techmaster.vn/2013/09/multipeer-connectivity-quick-tutorial/) and i've manage to send text or images. What i want to do is to stream video and audio from the camera of the one device (master) to the other device(slave) in real time and show it on the slave's screen. I've found ways to save the video from the camera to the device in a file but there is nothing about streaming. Any ideas? I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this API is designed to accept streaming file. You need to open a TCP socket on both the ends for doing a live streaming.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems there is the possibility create sessions and just send buffers of pictures or sound. Do you think this approach makes sense?

Comment: yes and that is what HTTP Live streaming does but its a huge project. Concatenating, video streams , resolving sync issues and much more. I am not sure if HTTP live streaming is used for video conf but most easiest way around this is to use RTSP over sockets.