# Video Streaming in Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, video-streaming, multipeer-connectivity

I am new to IOS and just started working on the MultiPeer Connectivity framework provided in IOS 7. I am able to transmit message and resources from one IOS 7 device to another through the delegate methods of Session Manager but I am not able to do the Video Streaming. I am using using the stream as follows:

```
NSOutputStream *stream = [mySessionManager.session startStreamWithName:@"streamMC" toPeer:(mySessionManager.peers [0]) error:&error];
```

And I am also using the delegate method :

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveStream:(NSInputStream *)stream withName:(NSString *)streamName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
{
    if ([streamName isEqualToString:@"streamMC"]) {
    {

    }
}
```

But I dont know how to implement video streaming within this method, and how to generate stream. I referred to this link also :
 http://techmaster.vn/2013/09/multipeer-connectivity-quick-tutorial/
but a blank method for receiving stream is provided.
 Can anyone give a more clear picture to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will doing similar stuff this week, gonna get back with the results.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the response. Please do inform if you get something useful.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150337/multipeer-connectivity-for-video-streaming-between-iphones helpful

Comment: The other post is helpful, but it sends one image at a time rather than a stream.  I do would love to see what kind of speed improvement streaming provides!  Where's that "bounty" button when you need it!?!

Comment: There will be no speed improvement whatsoever. I've tried both ways. If you'd like code that sends image data the fastest, simply request it and I'll provide.