# how to get correct Video Orientation correctly in iOS after save to server

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, alasset

I tried below code to convert video from `ALAsset` to `NSData`, this `NSData` is submitting to the server correctly.

**Problem:**

But the problem is when I get the thumbnail from NSData in the server, the image is not oriented correctly for some videos and showing correctly for other videos. Also i feel that Video also not oriented correctly.

So do I have to include any thing extra in my code. I know how to orient Image but I don't know how to orient correctly a video.

```
-(NSData *)ConvertVideoToNSData:(ALAsset *)asset{

NSData *VideoData;
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

        Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
        NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
        VideoData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
        return VideoData;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the video data is bad, not thumbnails generation itself ?

Comment: You can try to use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4684110/792677), but what you really need to do is to correct the question (with the title) because it is too board, unclear and it contradicts itself.

Comment: Ok. I already checked that link. But it suggest to make orientation from server. What i want is to make correct orientation from device it self.

Comment: Separate comment, what are you doing with the VideoData to convert it to video? I'm struggling with this problem on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390679/convert-incoming-nsstream-to-view

Comment: Eric, Am not converting VideoData to video on device. When i uploading (POST) VideoData to server am storing video in some folder then getting the URL of that video and playing that video with `MPMoviePlayerViewController` . My problem is regarding orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
CGSize dimesions = [representation dimensions];
if (dimesions.height > dimesions.width)
    orientation = 1; //Portrait
else
    orientation = 0; //Lanscape
```