# Streaming microphone audio over MCSession

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth

I have an app that used to use `GKSession` for voice communication between multiple devices. In particular, I used `[GKVoiceChatService defaultVoiceChatService]` to establish voice communications. Although deprecated back in iOS 7, this continued to work well until now: in iOS 9 this functionality works only over wifi, but not Bluetooth (which is a requirement for my app).

While trying to convert this to use `MCSession`, I stumbled at the part where audio streaming comes in. I can successfully connect peers over `MCSession`, but cannot figure out how to treat audio.

I have seen some tutorials on streaming camera video: [multipeer connectivity for video streaming between iphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150337/multipeer-connectivity-for-video-streaming-between-iphones)
And for streaming audio from a file: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity

However, I still cannot quite come up with a way to stream audio from the microphone. Anyone have any tips?