# MCSession & AVFoundation video streaming

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avfoundation, multipeer-connectivity

I want to send video from a device to another using Multipeer Connectivity framework.

After establishing the connection between the peers I'm capturing the video from the front camera using a regular `AVCaptureSession`.

I'm following these steps.

1) Open the stream:

```
func setupStreaming() {
    if let stream = p2pSession.startStream() {
        stream.delegate = self
        stream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        stream.open()
        self.outputStream = stream
    }
}
```

The `p2pSession.startStream()` method creates a stream to the peer in the established `MCSession` session and returns it if no exception.

2) When the video output notifies a frame has been captured it calls its delegate method

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // ¿?
}
```

3) In the the delegate method of the `MCSession` I have to get the input stream and extract the data.

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    stream.delegate = self
    stream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    stream.open()        
    // ¿?
}
```

As you can see steps 2) and 3) are empty. I'm completely lost about how to achieve the conversion between the `CMSampleBuffer` and the `OutputStream`, and between the `InputStream` and the final view that would render each video frame.

I've search a lot and I can't see anything that I can understand completely because I have lacks on streaming, video buffers and related. For example this code, I can't understand exactly what it is doing:

```
guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
        return
    }
let flags = CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0)
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, flags)
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
let src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
let data: NSData = NSData(bytes: src_buff, length: bytesPerRow * height)
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, flags)
let auxData = data as Data
auxData.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    outputStream?.write(bytes, maxLength: auxData.count)
}
```

I saw an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150337/multipeer-connectivity-for-video-streaming-between-iphones) of this but using `MCSession`'s `send(_ data: Data, toPeers peerIDs: [MCPeerID], with mode: MCSessionSendDataMode)`, not the streaming API (I think that is the correct way to do this).

Also, the docs are very cryptic to me.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered dispatching in serial queue?

Comment: Hi @Yaman. What relation has the queue with my problem?

Comment: Is ensures the sample buffers are sent in the correct order

Comment: Did you solved it?